# Java - Non-lexicographical reverse order with Integers in max heap

Tags: java

Collections.reverseOrder() comparator does lexicographical sorting when used with a max heap toArray function.

Example: 4, 35, 41 would print as 41, 4, 35.

What I want is for it to print as 41, 35, 4

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
maxHeap.add(4);

//Prints [4]
System.out.println("MaxHeap:"+ Arrays.toString(maxHeap.toArray()));

maxHeap.add(35);

//Prints [35, 4]
System.out.println("MaxHeap:"+ Arrays.toString(maxHeap.toArray()));

maxHeap.add(41);

//Prints [41, 4, 35]
System.out.println("MaxHeap:"+ Arrays.toString(maxHeap.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 4):

The default comparator of an Integer is not lexicographical.

The problem is that the internal array used by an PriorityQueue (which is what `toArray()` returns) is not sorted.

To get the elements in the sorted order you need to call the `poll()` method in the PriorityQueue until there are no more elements. This how the PriorityQueue functions by definition.

Comment: javadoc of `toArray()` states "_The elements are in no particular order._" - upvoted

Comment: Or, you know, just print the queue.toString().

Comment: @Daniel you are wrong the `toString()` just returns the internal no-sorted array.